# RTKQuery create another request even if i add data to the cache with upsertQueryData

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

i have and Api Slice like so:

```
export const marketApi = ApiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    tagTypes: ['Market'],
    keepUnusedDataFor: 1,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getInstrument: builder.query({
            query: (refId) => ({
                url: `/market/instruments/${refId}`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
                arg,
                { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved, dispatch }
            ) {
                await cacheDataLoaded;
                const payload = `instruments.${arg}`;

                // Listen for messages
                const onMessage = (message) => {
                    if (message.path === payload) {
                        // console.log('message', message);
                        updateCachedData((draft) => {
                            // TODO: (fix this later) maybe something otherThan tradeSummary Changed
                            const updateInstrument = {
                                ...draft,
                                tradeSummary: {
                                    ...draft?.tradeSummary,
                                    ...message.value?.tradeSummary
                                }
                            };

                            Object.assign(draft, updateInstrument);
                        });
                    }
                };

                // subs to socket
                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.subscribeSocket.initiate(payload));
                dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.channel.initiate(onMessage));

                await cacheEntryRemoved;
            }
        }),
        getBulkInstrument: builder.query({
            query: ({ refIds, size }) => ({
                url: `/market/instrument-details?${ParamsHandler({
                    filter: `refId IN '${refIds.join(',')}'`,
                    size
                })}`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            async onCacheEntryAdded(
                arg,
                { cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved, dispatch, getCacheEntry }
            ) {
                await cacheDataLoaded;

                const { refIds } = arg;
                const instrumentList = getCacheEntry().data;

                // subscribe socket
                refIds.forEach((refId) => {
                    dispatch(ApiSlice.endpoints.subscribeSocket.initiate(`instruments.${refId}`));
                });

                instrumentList.forEach((inst) => {
                    dispatch(
                        ApiSlice.util.upsertQueryData('getInstrument', inst.instrument.refId, inst)
                    );
                });

                await cacheEntryRemoved;
            }
        }),
    }),

});
```

basically what you see is two endpoint one is `getInstrument` for fetching individual instrument and use `refID` as an argument. the other one is `getBulkInstrument` for fetching many instrument at once and used a list of `[refIds]` as an argument.

what i try to do is simple.

- I used `getBulkInstrument` endpoint to fetch many instrument (and subscribe to each instrument).
- after i fetched all instruments I use the `upsertQueryData` to add each instrument into the cache of `getInstrument` so when `useGetInstrumentQuery` called it find specific instrument in the cache and dose not make new request for that.

everything in this code works fine as expected but my problem is `useGetInstrumentQuery` create new request to the server anyway !

according to this [link](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates#creating-new-cache-entries-or-replacing-existing-ones), I need to "preventing an extra fetch to retrieve the item later".